# Programming an EL Sequencer

Tags: atmega328

I have a [EL Sequencer](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12781) and [FTDI 5V breakout board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9716).  I have been have been unable to program it.  All my attempts get some variation of "programmer is not responding".

I was using these [instructions](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sound-reactive-el-wire-costume) as a starting place.  I soldered the 6 pinholes as indicated.  I have connected everything.  I am not sure if I should switch the FTDI jumper to 3.3V (it is currently at 5V).  The pin in the EL Sequencer is labelled 5V, but the instructions also say "the EL Sequencer runs an ATmega328p at 8 MHz and 3.3V".  Should I change the jumper to 3.3V?

I have downloaded the latest IDE from [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/software).  But there is no board option for the EL Sequencer.  What board should I select?

Anything else I need to do to program the EL Sequencer?

Thank you,

Comment: is the FTDI board working correctly?

Comment: I am not sure how to check.  It was new when I purchased it.

Comment: just because it is new does not mean that it works ......... connect `RX` and `TX` together ..... plug the module into your computer .... open serial monitor, choose the correct com port ..... type something on the keyboard ..... you should see the characters on the screen .... you should also see the LEDs on the module flash

Comment: Thank you for telling me how to test the FTDI.  I did as you suggested and received the same characters that I typed.  I also saw the LED on the FTDI flash.  It appears the FTDI is working.  Is there a similar way to check the EL Sequencer?

Comment: no there is not .... just connect everything together as before and try choosing Arduino Uno in the Arduino IDE